# Como achar uma string baseando-se em um grupo de expressões regulares

Tags: php, regex

Estou a tentar criar um *Template Engine* em PHP por questões de estudo.

Suponhamos que eu tenha o seguinte *array*:

```
$regexList = [
  'varPattern' => '/{{\s*\$(.*?)\s*}}/',
  'loopPattern' => '/@for\((.*?)\)\s*{{((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)}}/',
  'statementPattern' => '/@if\((.*?)\)\s*{{((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)}}/'
]
```

e as seguites *funções*:

```
getVar($nomeDaVariavel);
loop($nomeDoArray);
getStatementResult($expressãoBooleana);
```

e a seguinte *string*:

```
$string = '

<span>{{ $nomeCompleto }}</span>

@for($nomes as $nome)
{{
  @if($nome == 'Eleandro)
  {{
    <p>{{ $nome }}</p>
  }}
}} ';
```

A ideia é ler a *string* de cima para baixo e baseando-se na lista de expressões regulares achar o resultado e entregá-lo a função correcta.

Por exemplo: A primeira coisa a ser achada tem de ser a `{{ $string }}`, então passamos o nome da variável a função `getVar($nomeDaVariávelEncontrada)`.

A seguir será o *loop*, então chamamos o `loop($comoNomeDoArrayEncontrado)`; e dentro do *loop* será encontrado o `if`, então pegamos o conteúdo do `if` e entregamo-lo a função `getStatementResult($expressãoBooleanaEncontrada)` com o valor encontrado.

Como eu posso fazer isso na ordem certa (de cima para baixo)?

Comment: Nesse caso, seria interessante utilizar o padrão interpreter, pois, é evidente que seu problema gera uma estrutura composite. No momento, estou sem tempo para formular uma solução.

Comment: Não estou entendendo sua pergunta, o RegexList tem 3 RegEx's dentro dele, porque não chamar somente um deles quando existe a necessidade e atribuir na variavel, usando-a na hora que precisar? Não existe um método que faça o código "ler" de cima para baixo, ele já faz isso naturalmente, basta você estruturar corretamente.

Comment: @Paz Estou usando o preg_replace_callback para substituir os resultados das _patterns_ que estão no **$regexList**. Como pode ver [aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), essa _função_ recebe também um _array_ com _patterns__ (no caso o **$regexList**. O problema é que essa _função_ pega a ocorrência da primeira _pattern_ no $regexList, em vez de pegar a primeira ocorrência na $string que tenha uma _pattern_ no **$regexList**, entende?

Comment: Eu não sei o que posso encontrar primeiro na **$string**, pode ser um **@if**, um **@for** ou um **{{$var}}**, mas sei que eu devo substituir as ocorrências que aparecerem primeiro na **$string**, no caso, a primeira ocorrência seria **{{$var}}, então eu substituiria **{{$var}}** com alguma coisa, a segunda seria **@for**, então eu executaria o loop, e por aí fora... É isto que não estou a conseguir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Estou usando o `preg_replace_callback` para substituir os resultados das patterns que estão no `$regexList`.
>   [...] O problema é que essa função pega a ocorrência da primeira pattern no `$regexList`, em vez de pegar **a primeira ocorrência na `$string`** que tenha uma pattern no `$regexList`.

**Use apenas um regex.**

Nesse caso, não use um array. Em vez disto:

```
$regexList = [
                 '/regex1/',
                 '/regex2/',
                 '/regex3/',
             ];
```

Use isto:

```
$regex = '/regex1|regex2|regex3/';
```

Na função:

```
$resultado = preg_replace_callback(
                 $regex,
                 function ($matches) {
                     // ...
                     return 'substituído';
                 },
                 $texto
             );
```

---

**Mas como sabe qual regex foi encontrado?**

Pode usar grupos para identificá-los.

```
$regex = '/(regex1)|(regex2)|(regex3)/';
```

Então:

```
$resultado = preg_replace_callback(
                 $regex,
                 function ($matches) {
                     if ($matches[1]) {
                         return 'regex1 substituído';
                     } else if ($matches[2]) {
                         return 'regex2 substituído';
                     } else if ($matches[3]) {
                         return 'regex3 substituído';
                     }
                 },
                 $texto
             );
```

Mas você tem outros grupos nos padrões, e contar o número certo do grupo pode ser complicado. Podemos usar **grupos nomeados** para facilitar as coisas.

```
$regex = '/(?P<padrao1>regex1)|(?P<padrao2>regex2)|(?P<padrao3>regex3)/';


$resultado = preg_replace_callback(
                 $regex,
                 function ($matches) {
                     if ($matches['padrao1']) {
                         return 'regex1 substituído';

                     } else if ($matches['padrao2']) {
                         return 'regex2 substituído';

                     } else if ($matches['padrao3']) {
                         return 'regex3 substituído';
                     }
                 },
                 $texto
             );
```

---

**Código**

Para responder sua pergunta, com um pouco de recursão:

```php
function analisar( $string ) {
    $regex = '/
                    (?P<var>       {{\s*\$(.*?)\s*}}                      )
                |
                    (?P<loop>      @for\((.*?)\)\s*{{((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)}}  )
                |
                    (?P<statement> @if\((.*?)\)\s*{{((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)}}   )
              /x';

    $resultado = preg_replace_callback(
                     $regex,
                     function ($matches) {
                         /*
                             //debug
                             echo "\n\nSubst: $matches[0]\n\$matches = ";
                             var_export($matches);
                         */
                         if ($matches['var']) {
                             return getVar($matches[2]);

                         } else if ($matches['loop']) {
                             return loop($matches[4], $matches[5]);

                         } else if ($matches['statement']) {
                             return getStatementResult($matches[7], $matches[8]);
                         }
                     },
                     $string
                 );

    return $resultado;
}

function getVar($nomeDaVariavel){
    return 'VAR('
        . analisar($nomeDaVariavel)
        . ')';
}
function loop($nomeDoArray, $codigo){
    return "LOOP\nLOOP-COND("
        . analisar($nomeDoArray)
        . ")\nLOOP-CODIGO("
        . analisar($codigo)
        . ')';
}
function getStatementResult($expressãoBooleana, $codigo){
    return "IF\nIF-COND("
        . analisar($expressãoBooleana)
        . ")\nIF-CODIGO("
        . analisar($codigo)
        . ')';
}
```

Teste:

```php
$string = '
<span>{{ $nomeCompleto }}</span>

@for($nomes as $nome)
{{
  @if($nome == \'Eleandro\')
  {{
    <p>{{ $nome }}</p>
  }}
}} 
';

echo analisar($string);
```

Resultado:

```
<span>VAR(nomeCompleto)</span>

LOOP
LOOP-COND($nomes as $nome)
LOOP-CODIGO(
  IF
IF-COND($nome == 'Eleandro')
IF-CODIGO(
    <p>VAR(nome)</p>
  )
)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/pBfQBP

Comment: Obrigadasso mano. Mais vale tarde do que nunca.